# When is the site going to be out of beta?

Tags: discussion, beta

I'm sure I've read it somewhere already, but I can't seem to find it now.  Does StackExchange have a page where they have published the milestones required for a site to progress through its various development phases?  How close are we to being out of Beta, and becoming a full-fledged site?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Changes to Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) entry on the Stack Exchange Blog...

> This phase will last between 60 and 90 days. At the end of that period, the site will need to reach a minimum critical mass to continue and move on to full citizenship.

Comment: Ok, need to create critical mass, Go!